# How to get kendo grid filed value?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I use kendo grid template field. I want to get `S_DATA` field value.
It is not working.
What is the problem?

```
field:'S_DATA', title:'CONTENT', width:'20%', 
    attributes: {style:'text-align:center'}, 
    headerAttributes:{style:'text-align:center'},
    template: 
    "<div class='k-block k-success-colored'>
     #if (#=S_DATA#.length >= 100) 
       {#<span> test  </span>#} 
     else 
      {#<span>#:S_DATA#</span>#} #
    </div>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template is not valid, you need to use the variable `S_DATA` not the value `#=S_DATA#` inside the if-expression.

Change

```
...
#if (#=S_DATA#.length >= 100) 
...
```

to

```
...
#if (S_DATA.length >= 100) 
...
```

I've create a [Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/efUfo) showing a working example.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this pattern in templates. I know it will be confusing some times

```
template : #{JS/KENDO Entities}# <HTML OR TEXT Entities> #{JS/KENDO Entities}#
```